# Вывод изображения при нажатии на кнопку

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode

есть массив состаящий из 9 картинок.
при нажатии на кнопку поисходит смена картинки.
Когда доходит до последнего элемента - все начинается по новой

```
    - (IBAction)pushButtonAction:(id)sender
{
    _ingaIndex++;
       if (_ingaIndex == _ingas.count) {
           _ingaIndex = 0;

    }
    self.imageView.image = [_ingas objectAtIndex:_ingaIndex];
}
```

Требуется изменить так, чтоб при нжатии на кнопку после показа последнего изображения показывалось окно alertView с 2 кнопками.

Прошу вашей помощи.

Comment: А в чём проблема?

Comment: не хватает знаний изменить данный код,
здесь я так понимаю когда _ingaIndex становится равной массиву- опять идет показ с первой картинки.А требуется сделать чтоб после показа последней картинки, нажимая еще раз единственную кнопку-выскакивало окно с текстом и 2 кнопками

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if(ingaIndex>8)
        {
            UIAlertView *message = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Hello World!"
                                                              message:@"This is your first UIAlertview message."
                                                             delegate:nil
                                                    cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel"
                                                    otherButtonTitles:nil];
            [message addButtonWithTitle:@"Button 2"];
            [message show];
        }
else
{
//всё что было раньше
}
```